# How to decide stack size of thread in c for any scenario?

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, real-time

On working with a real-time application I am not able to decide the thread stack size, calculating depth is not possible since thread is triggering Api's whose code is not visible. Since its real-time application, testing is not possible either. Memory is at premium since its a real time system.

Is there any heuristics to calculate thread size?

Comment: How can there possibly be a general heuristic? It all depends on how much data the thread uses and how deeply nested the function calls are. It's totally application-dependent.

Comment: Can you please give us some information about the hardware. Like for example is the memory counted in KiB or MiB? Tens or hundreds? As for your programs, will there be deep recursion? Any recursion at all? Tens of functions? Hundreds of functions? How deep will the call-stack become? Will there be strings or arrays on the stack? Functions with many variable or many arguments?

Comment: ...then there's interrupt stack use..  Are driver interrupts handled on the stack of the interrupted thread or do they switch to a dedicated interrupt stack?  Can interrupts nest?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know it precisely, you need to measure it.

As you do not know the stack usage af the API, I would personally fill the sack with a known value and after your program tests find the maximum usage (ie where the known value was overwritten by other values).

That is the most precise way and it is used frequently by the embedded system programmers (some RTOSes have even built-in functions for this task),

Answer (score 0):

> On working with a real-time application I am not able to decide the thread stack size, calculating depth is not possible since thread is triggering Api's whose code is not visible. Since its real-time application, testing is not possible either. Memory is at premium since its a real time system.

1. Stack size should not be a concern when designing an application.  You should study the supporg given by your multithreading libray, as the stack size is not normally decided beforehand (most operating systems allow the stack to grow as needed, allocating pages when the need arises)
2. What do you mean that the thread is triggering api code that is not visible?  That's not a good design approach to have a real time application.
3. Testing is a must in a real time application, at least as it is for any other application.  If you say *testing is not possible* I'm afraid you'll never have a working application.  I'm not aware (even D. Knuth got bugs in TeX ---The current version of TeX is 3.141592653; it was last updated in 2021--- this means at least 9 bugs where identified and repaired, but still he has not lost a fortune, just 512$ ---he started paying one(1) dollar to the first bug, and doubling the quantity for each successive bug found and notified to him--- to pay in total) on how you plan to test your code, but testing under the final platform is not recomendable for embedded or systems programming, as many things can be tested and verified without doing in field testing.
4. You have not specified any context you are using in your problem, nor the libraries you use for multi threading, nor if you have operating system support for threading or you have to program it yourself (yes, not always multithreading happens magically, sometimes you have to implement it when you need and it is not provided)

As a hint, I'll tell you that, if your application is truely real-time, you
had better to do your own context switching module and control things like virtual memory (if you have it) or paging (as it involves far more undesired transparent delays induced by virtual memory.  If you are in the case that you have to stick on a small or fixed amount of stack per thread, then you had better not to use virtual paged memory or automatic allocated stacks, arrange a fixed amount per stack (so the stack doesn't grow dynamically) and place it in the global variables segment.